# Split a whole column of a data frame and keep only the first part

Tags: r

Using a simple string like this:

```
a <- "l_Gf43qCW2r&auty=in_out"
```

I can keep only the first part using this:

```
b <- strsplit(a, "&auty=")[[1]][1]
```

I would like to make the same for a whole column from a dataframe. I tried this:

```
n = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      c <- strsplit(df$col1[n], "&auty=")[[1]][1]
      n = n + 1
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
Error in strsplit(df$col1[n], "&auty=") : non-character argument
```

Is there any different way for dataframes to make it?

Comment: It would make sense to post the result of `dput(df)`, so we can see what your `df` looks like. Side note: you can remove the `n = 1` before the loop and `n = n + 1` inside the loop. Replace the `strsplit(df$col1[n], "&auty=")[[1]][1]` with `strsplit(df$col1[i], "&auty=")[[1]][1]`.

Comment: or make a function `> splitr <- function(x){
     strsplit(x, "&auty=")[[1]][1]
 }
`

Comment: Paste the result of `dput(df$col1)` if your problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$col1), "&auty="), '[[', 1))
```

Applying `strsplit` on the whole column `col1` of data frame `df` will give you a list in which every element contains the first and second part of the split. By doing so, you extract the first part of each list's element and `unlist` will give you the result in the form of vector.

`as.character(df$col1)` will presumably fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
 sapply(df$col1,function(x) gsub("&auty=.*","",x))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `sub`

```
sub("&auty.*", "", a)
#[1] "l_Gf43qCW2r"
```